# Performance of OCIStmtFetch

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

My application uses Oracle table having 70+ columns and the table contains 2.5 Million records. My application has to fetch all the data in the table and do some processing on each record. However It currently takes about 25 seconds to complete the task. I did some profiling and figured out that my application only uses 8% of the CPU and 92% CPU taken by the OCIStmtFetch (or OCIStmtFetch2) function. The application took almost 100% CPU and I feel nothing to optimize in my code.

My entire database table is 815 MBs and I'm using variable defining for the cursor and bulk fecth of 25,000.

As per my understanding the bottleneck in the OCIStmtFetch.

Can some please advice are there any way of optimizing this.

Comment: Generally Oracle steals far more CPU than it needs; this isn't normally indicative of any issue. You're currently executing 100 queries against your database, which are each reading 8MB each, I assume not using an index, in 0.25s. This seems relatively reasonable, depending on the box you're using. If you really need all the table why not just execute a single statement to get it (should take ~1s assuming good enough disks/network etc) or start gathering data asynchronously?

Comment: Thanks, I use only one statement (One cursor, OCIStmtPrepare called only once). However fetching of 25000 at a single fetch. If I want to fetch 2.5 million at once it needs a larger amount of memory for define variables. Isn't it?